# Inno Setup, How to restrict installation to specific hardware configuration?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, hardware

I am new to Inno Setup and I have a program which is a 64 bit application and tested on Intel processors. It needs 4 GB RAM and runs on some graphic cards and ...

How can I create a setup that check target computer and if it is not compatible, it stops installing and give proper error information to user?

Can I do this without writing Inno Setup scripts?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict installation to x64 systems, use [`ArchitecturesAllowed` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesallowed):

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
```

---

For memory checks and graphics card check, there's no native support. You have use Pascal Scripting.

For memory check, see
[Inno Setup - How can I check system specs before/during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17026867/850848)