# Query available RAM in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to get the available RAM to determinate some characteristics to my software.

I have this code to show my PC's RAM:

```pascal
type
  DWORDLONG = Int64;
  TMemoryStatusEx = record
    dwLength: DWORD;
    dwMemoryLoad: DWORD;
    ullTotalPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual: DWORDLONG;
  end;

function GlobalMemoryStatusEx(var lpBuffer: TMemoryStatusEx): BOOL;
  external 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  MemoryStatus: TMemoryStatusEx;
  RAM: String;
begin
  Result := True;
  MemoryStatus.dwLength := SizeOf(MemoryStatus);
  if GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MemoryStatus) then
  begin
    RAM := Int64ToStr(MemoryStatus.ullTotalPhys/1000000000);
    MsgBox('This PC has '+RAM+' GB of RAM', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Based on [Inno Setup - How can I check system specs before/during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026867/inno-setup-how-can-i-check-system-specs-before-during-installation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the code for `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` from [Inno Setup - How can I check system specs before/during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17026867/850848), just use the `ullAvailPhys` field.

---

Another possibility is using [WMI query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/querying-wmi):

```pascal
var
  Query: string;
  WbemLocator, WbemServices, WbemObjectSet: Variant;
  OperatingSystem: Variant;
begin
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\CIMV2');
  Query := 'SELECT FreePhysicalMemory FROM Win32_OperatingSystem';
  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery(Query);
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin
    OperatingSystem := WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(0);
    Log(Format('Free physical memory = %d GB', [
      Integer(OperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory div (1024*1024))]));
  end;
end;
```

See also [Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40762683/850848) (shows, among other, how to retrieve total physical memory using WMI query).

Comment: Thank you, that will be of great help to me.

Comment: I have discovered that on some PCs testing available memory using WMI - is a very slow and resource intensive task.

Answer (score 1):

Read `ullAvailPhys` field:

```pascal
type
  DWORDLONG = Int64;
  TMemoryStatusEx = record
    dwLength: DWORD;
    dwMemoryLoad: DWORD;
    ullTotalPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual: DWORDLONG;
  end;

function GlobalMemoryStatusEx(var lpBuffer: TMemoryStatusEx): BOOL;
  external 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  MemoryStatus: TMemoryStatusEx;
  RAM, Available: String;
begin
  Result := True;
  MemoryStatus.dwLength := SizeOf(MemoryStatus);
  { if the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function call succeed, then... }
  if GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MemoryStatus) then
  begin
    RAM := Int64ToStr(MemoryStatus.ullTotalPhys/1000000000);
    Available := Int64ToStr(MemoryStatus.ullAvailPhys/1000000000)
    MsgBox('This PC has '+RAM+' GB of RAM, Available ' + Available, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If it was obvious then why ask?

Comment: I am new to programming, I am new to this page, I have almost no knowledge of Pascalscript, my language is not English so even asking here is difficult for me, when I asked the question had not looked the answer, So I'm sorry if that bothers you.