# Report installed .NET Framework version during install with Inno Setup

Tags: .net, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am experimenting with Inno Setup in preparation for creating an installer. My first attempt is to report back to the user which .NET Framework is currently installed. I came up with the following script, which installs a token exe but it does not show the message box that I wanted to display the installed Framework version.

```
[Setup]
AppName=NETFramework_Test
AppVersion=1.0.0
DefaultDirName=c:\al\NetFWTest\test
WizardStyle=modern
OutputDir=c:\al\NetFWTest

[Files]
Source: "c:\al\computer\miscsmallapps\tmpdir\tmpdir.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  VersionNum: cardinal;

begin
  if RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full',
       'Version', VersionNum) then
    begin
      MsgBox('The installed .NET Framework version:' + IntToStr(VersionNum),
        mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end
  else
    begin
      MsgBox('Error reading the Registry...', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your code from some [Inno Setup event function, like `InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents).

For an example, see [Inno Setup - How can I check system specs before/during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17026867/850848)

---

Also, the `Version` value is string, so you need to use [`RegQueryStringValue`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue).

Answer (score 1):

Why do this manually when you can already use [`IsDotNetInstalled`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isdotnetinstalled)?

For example:

```pascal
[Code]
// InitializeSetup is called when the setup is starting.
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if not IsDotNetInstalled(net462, 0) then
  begin
    MsgBox('The required .NET Framework version 4.6.2 is not installed.',
      mbError, MB_OK)
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```